# First row of a table on a new page

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have a requirement that the first row on that page of a table (not the header) is different from the rest. I can't figure out if it can be done with markers or if it's even possible with just FO.

I basically have a legend for a graphic that would be tagged something like:

```
<row>
   <callout>1</callout>
   <name>Cog</name>
   <description>Super important for stuff</description>
</row>
<row>
   <callout>2</callout>
   <name>Sprocket</name>
   <description>Not nearly as important for stuff</description>
</row>
<row>
   <callout>3</callout>
   <name>Sprigot</name>
   <description>I'm not creative</description>
</row>
<row>
   <callout>4</callout>
   <name>Last One</name>
   <description>Blah blah blah</description>
</row>
```

The table would output as (X is a count for the number of tables):

| Callout | Name | Desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X - 1 | Cog | Super important for stuff |
| - 2 | Sprocket | Not nearly as important for stuff |
| - 3 | Sprigot | I'm not creative |

`page break`

| Callout | Name | Desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X - 4 | Last One | Blah blah blah |

The count only shows up on the first row on that page, but may obviously show up multiple times if the table spans multiple pages. Is there any way to get it to output like that? I'm using XSL 2.0, Saxon 9, and Apache FOP 2.7.

```
<xsl:template match="table">
   <fo:table>
      <fo:table-column column-width="20%"/>
      <fo:table-column column-width="30%"/>
      <fo:table-column column-width="40%"/>
      <fo:table-header>
         <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
               <fo:block>Callout</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell>
               <fo:block>Name</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell>
               <fo:block>Desc</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
         </fo:table-row>
      </fo:table-header>
      <fo:table-body>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </fo:table-body>
   </fo:table>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="row">
   <fo:row>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </fo:row>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="callout">
   <fo:table-cell>
      <!-- The code needs to go here to get the count to appear only if this row is the first row on the page. -->
      <fo:block>
         <xsl:text>&#160;-&#160;</xsl:text>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </fo:block>
   </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="name">
   <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </fo:block>
   </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="description">
   <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </fo:block>
   </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please share your current xslt  and the expected fo-xml.

Comment: I've added the basic xslt code and marked where the magic needs to happen. With table markers only being allowed in the header or footer of the table, I'm not sure how to get it to output like I need.

Comment: Please read your question and think how would someone understand what you mean. Your question literally says:

"I have a requirement that the first row on that page of a table (not the header) is different from the rest. "

Huh? What does that mean? Please explain.

Comment: Because ... frankly ... I would think that "the first row of any table is not the same as the header" ... but I still do not know what you mean.

Comment: @KevinBrown I tried to explain it farther in the post. “The count only shows up on the first row on that page, but may obviously show up multiple times if the table spans multiple pages.” Every row in the body of the table has the 3 columns. The first row on each page. Needs an enumeration added to the first column in addition to the value for that cell.

Comment: If in your example "X" would be 1 assuming it is the first table then you likely need table-markers. I do not think FOP supports them but I may be wrong. You could try to mimic something with headers markers pulled into an absolute position but it may not work if rows are allowed to split pages

Comment: @KevinBrown Thank you sir. And yes, the X would be 1 in the first table. I think FOP has minimal support for table-markers, but the retrieve has to be in the header or footer. The best I’ve been able to come up with is to try to output it in a second row in the header but try to make it look like it’s not part of the header. I should be able to make sure the rows don’t split pages.

Comment: Does the table always start a page? Or can it start in the middle?

Comment: @KevinBrown the table can start a page, but it follows an illustration so it depends on how big the illustration is.